# Docker: Nginx + PHP-FPM and multiple sites

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I'm new in Docker, and I'm searching about to install multiple sites in differents containers.

I made 2 containers, 1 with Nginx and 1 with php-fpm, sharing a volumen with the PHP files.

My idea is create 1 Nginx container for each site, but I don't want to create 1 php-fpm container for each site.

What is the best way to have multiple site with Docker ?

**UPDATE**

I made my own Docker image, with Nginx and PHP-FPM, based on the official Nginx image. Both services in the same container.

https://hub.docker.com/r/dignajar/nginx-php-fpm/

Answer (score 1):

A common practise today is having PHP-FPM and nginx in each container. Most of the load will be on PHP-FPM anyway, so even though it's not a 100% single application container, nginx overhead can be considered negligible.

Once you have dedicated containers for each application (website), you can use something like [this](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) to add yet another nginx layer that will route requests and make your experience more comfortable.